# Directives with non-isolated scope and event handlers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a simple directive to add a clear button to `input` fields.

```
angular.module('module').directive('strClearable', ($compile) => ({
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) => {
            const template = $compile('<span ng-click="reset()">&times</span>')(scope);
            el.after(template);

            scope.reset = () => {
                ngModel.$setViewValue('test');
                ngModel.$render();
            };
        },
    })
);

<input type="text" ng-model="something" str-clearable>
```

This works flawlessly as long as it is only used once per page. If there are several `input`s, each with the directive applied, clearing will not work properly anymore. It always just clears the last `input` of the page. This seems to be caused by the `scope.reset` method that is overwritten each time the directive is applied to an `input` field. As a result, `ngModel` will always point the to last `input` model.

How can I rewrite the directive to work for each `input` instead without adding an isolated scope?

Comment: you dont use isolate scope so all inputs are binded. Add: `scope:{},` to directive definition

Comment: @MaximShoustin I would like to avoid an isolated scope, otherwise I cannot apply other directives that already have one.

Comment: Avoid writing to `scope` when you use this approach. Assign `click` events to element directly instead of `ng-click`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
angular.module('module').directive('strClearable', () => ({
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) => {
            var btn = angular.element('<span>&times</span>');
            el.after(btn);

            btn.on('click', function() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue('');
              ngModel.$render();
              el[0].focus();
            });

        },
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works when executing `ngModel.$setViewValue(''); ngModel.$render();` in the click handler.

Comment: @str, yeah, `ngModel.$setViewValue` is a better solution because `scope[attrs.ngModel]` won't work on binding like this `ng-model="something.else"`. Updated the answer.